# Jquery IsNumeric with a not condition

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery to check to see if something isNumeric.
How do I check to see if it is not numeric?

```
    if  (IsNumeric($('#Amount').val())) { .....
```

I put a ! before IsNumeric but that did not work.

Comment: `isNaN($('#Amount').val()))`?

Comment: `$.isNan` got removed in 1.7 I believe, in favor of `$.isNumeric`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your call to the function is a little off. It should be `jQuery.isNumeric()` or `$.isNumeric()`, so your code would look this:

```
if(!$.isNumeric($('#Amount').val())) {
   // do something
}
```